# Problem importing a module from an express app in a script outside of express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a vanilla Express app whose package.json looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "express-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
}
```

And I want to write a script outside the express app that imports a module from the express app. The module resides in `./src/model/Example.js` That module also imports various other modules.

The script is located at `./scripts/test.mjs` and does:

`import Example from '../src/models/Example.js';`

However, I'm getting this hitting the first import from `Example.js`:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How do I structure this such that the script can import the module correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It is because your project in vanilla JS, the import statement is not going to work. You can use [parceljs](https://parceljs.org/javascript.html) a zero config package bundler which supports ES6 and above syntax to use it first add it as a dev dependency by running

```sh
npm install parcel-bundler --save-dev
```

And then add to scripts to your `package`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel <your entry file>",
    "build": "parcel build <your entry file>"
  }
}
```

replace the entry file with your main file in your code (example: `app.js`)

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
          const Example = require('../src/models/Example.js')
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that in Example it does imports so then the first import will hit an error

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do that is on yow package.json
Add a property call type and set the value of module

```
{
“name”;”project name”,
…
“type”;”module”,
…
“dependencies”:”….”,
}
```

by default nodejs treads yow code as
type: commons
It is why it says you cannot use import out side a module, bcuz yow package.json implicitly marks yow codes as type commonjs.
So after you set type module then you need to change the extension of them JavaScript files, from .js to `.mjs`. Yes you guessed right the m is from module.
You can do this or configure Babel, webpack, while you find the holy grail and what ever else is need it

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a monorepo approach using something like Lerna.

https://lerna.js.org/

So that you could create modules and dependencies directly inside your repository.